Heuristics for Dirichlet's Theorem with Central Limit Theorem
I'm watching this video lecture on
Number theory over function fields and
can't follow to the part on 'conceptional' reason for estimation
$$ \#\{p \in \Bbb P: p =a \ \text{mod} \ N, p <x \}
=\frac{1}{\Phi(N)}\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dy}{\log y} + O_{\epsilon}(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})  $$
mentioned in 18:20 based somehow on central limit theorem recasting
$O_{\epsilon}(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}) $ as error term of appropriate estimation
turning primes appearing in
$\{p \in \Bbb P: p =a \ \text{mod} \ N, p <x \}$ into random variables
associating to any $x$ the probability $1/ \log x $ fto be prime.
Could somebody elaborate the idea how one actually gets using this
stochastic approach via central limit theorem the exponent $\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$
in the error term? There are also
notes available
but they not clarify this argument.

See this question about square root cancellation and perhaps also these notes for a worked example of this kind of probabilistic estimate.

Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483070/approximation-on-dirichlets-arithmetic-progression-by-means-of-central-limit-th
